Unable to change texture of Gazebo oblect
I am writing a Gazebo 11.11 / ROS2 Galactic plugin to dynamically change texture. Here is what I have so far (looks scary, but most of it is error checking and print statements):
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <gazebo/rendering/rendering.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <gazebo_ros/node.hpp>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/image.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <OgreLogManager.h>

namespace gazebo
{
class LandscapeTexturePlugin : public ModelPlugin
{
public:
    LandscapeTexturePlugin() : ModelPlugin() 
    {
        Ogre::LogManager::getSingleton().createLog("/home/username/SnowCron/ros_projects/harsh/srcOgre.log", true, true, true);
    }

    void Load(physics::ModelPtr _model, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
    {
        // Store the model pointer
        this->model = _model;

        // Initialize ROS node
        this->ros_node = gazebo_ros::Node::Get(_sdf);

        // Create a subscriber for the texture update topic
        this->texture_sub = this->ros_node->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>(
            "update_landscape_texture", 10,
            std::bind(&LandscapeTexturePlugin::OnTextureUpdate, this, std::placeholders::_1));

        // Use a timer instead of connecting to the world update event
        this->update_timer = this->ros_node->create_wall_timer(
            std::chrono::milliseconds(100),
            std::bind(&LandscapeTexturePlugin::OnUpdate, this));
    }

private:
    void OnUpdate()
    {
        if (!this->visual && rendering::get_scene())
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Trying to find visual...");
            // this->visual = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<rendering::Visual>(
            //     rendering::get_scene()->GetVisual("ground_plane::landscape_link::visual"));
            std::string model_name = this->model->GetName();
            std::string visual_name = model_name + "::landscape_link::visual";
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Trying to find visual with name: %s", visual_name.c_str());
            this->visual = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<rendering::Visual>(rendering::get_scene()->GetVisual(visual_name));
            if (this->visual)
            {
                this->initial_material_name = this->visual->GetMaterialName();
                RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Visual found. Initial material: %s", this->initial_material_name.c_str());
            }
            else
            {
                RCLCPP_WARN(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> ! Visual not found");
            }
        }
    }
    
void OnTextureUpdate(const sensor_msgs::msg::Image::SharedPtr msg)
{
    try
    {
        if (!this->visual)
        {
            RCLCPP_WARN(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Visual not found yet. Skipping texture update.");
            return;
        }

        Ogre::Root::getSingletonPtr()->addResourceLocation(
            "/usr/share/gazebo-11/media",
            "FileSystem",
            "Gazebo");
        Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().initialiseAllResourceGroups();

        Ogre::Root* root = Ogre::Root::getSingletonPtr();
        if (!root)
        {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Ogre root not found. Ogre might not be properly initialized.");
            return;
        }

        // Convert ROS image to OpenCV format
        cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::RGB8);
        cv::Mat image = cv_ptr->image;

        // Create a new Gazebo texture
        common::Image gazebo_image;
        gazebo_image.SetFromData(image.data, image.cols, image.rows, common::Image::RGB_INT8);

        // Create a new material name
        std::string material_name = "LandscapeMaterial_" + std::to_string(this->texture_count++);

        RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Material Name: %s", this->visual->GetMaterialName().c_str());

        // Get the material
        Ogre::MaterialPtr ogre_material = Ogre::MaterialManager::getSingleton().getByName(
            this->visual->GetMaterialName(), Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME);

        if (!Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().resourceGroupExists(Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME)) 
        {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Resource group doesn't exist");
            Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().createResourceGroup(Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME);
        }

        if(ogre_material.isNull())
        {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Failed to get material, DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME: %s",
                Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME.c_str());
            return;
        }                

        Ogre::Technique* technique = ogre_material->getTechnique(0); // Assuming first technique
        Ogre::Pass* pass = technique->getPass(0); // Assuming first pass

        Ogre::TexturePtr texture;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pass->getNumTextureUnitStates(); ++i) 
        {
            Ogre::TextureUnitState* texUnit = pass->getTextureUnitState(i);
            Ogre::String textureName = texUnit->getTextureName();
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Texture name: %s", texUnit->getTextureName().c_str());
            texture = Ogre::TextureManager::getSingletonPtr()->getByName(textureName);
            if (!texture.isNull()) {
                break;  // Use the first valid texture found
            }    
        }

        if (texture.isNull()) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Texture is null; 05h");
            return;
        }

        Ogre::PixelFormat currentFormat = texture->getFormat();     // 26, PF_X8R8G8B8
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Current texture format: %d", currentFormat);

        // Convert RGB to BGRA (which is equivalent to X8R8G8B8 in this case)
        cv::Mat bgra_image;
        cv::cvtColor(image, bgra_image, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGRA);

        // Get the pixel depth of the texture
        size_t textureDepth = Ogre::PixelUtil::getNumElemBytes(texture->getFormat());
        size_t imageDepth = bgra_image.elemSize();

        Ogre::PixelBox pixelBox(Ogre::Box(0, 0, bgra_image.cols, bgra_image.rows), Ogre::PF_X8R8G8B8, bgra_image.data);

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Image dimensions: %d x %d, depth: %zu", bgra_image.cols, bgra_image.rows, imageDepth);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Texture dimensions: %d x %d, depth: %zu", texture->getWidth(), texture->getHeight(), textureDepth);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> PixelBox dimensions: %d x %d", pixelBox.getWidth(), pixelBox.getHeight());

        if (texture->getWidth() != bgra_image.cols || texture->getHeight() != bgra_image.rows) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Texture dimensions (%d x %d) don't match image dimensions (%d x %d)",
                         texture->getWidth(), texture->getHeight(), bgra_image.cols, bgra_image.rows);
        }

        if(!(texture->getUsage() & Ogre::TU_DYNAMIC_WRITE_ONLY_DISCARDABLE) ||
            (texture->getWidth() != bgra_image.cols || texture->getHeight() != bgra_image.rows || textureDepth != imageDepth)) 
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Creating buffer using createManual");

            Ogre::String textureName = texture->getName();
            Ogre::TextureManager::getSingleton().remove(textureName);
            texture = Ogre::TextureManager::getSingleton().createManual(
                textureName,
                Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
                Ogre::TEX_TYPE_2D,
                bgra_image.cols, bgra_image.rows,
                0,
                Ogre::PF_X8R8G8B8,
                Ogre::TU_DYNAMIC_WRITE_ONLY_DISCARDABLE
            );
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Creating buffer using createManual: done");
        }  
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> cols, rows: %d, %d", image.cols, image.rows);

        // Copy image data to the texture
        Ogre::HardwarePixelBufferSharedPtr pixelBuffer = texture->getBuffer();
        
        // Recalculate buffer size after potential texture recreation
        size_t bufferSizeBytes = pixelBuffer->getSizeInBytes();
        size_t imageSizeBytes = bgra_image.total() * bgra_image.elemSize();

        if (bufferSizeBytes < imageSizeBytes) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Pixel buffer size (%zu) is smaller than image data size (%zu)",
                         bufferSizeBytes, imageSizeBytes);
            return;
        }            

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Buffer obtained");

        // Update the texture
Lock the pixel buffer before writing
pixelBuffer->lock(Ogre::HardwareBuffer::HBL_DISCARD);
void* buffer = pixelBuffer->lock(Ogre::HardwareBuffer::HBL_DISCARD);

try {
    // Copy image data to the texture
    pixelBuffer->blitFromMemory(pixelBox);


//memcpy(buffer, bgra_image.data, bgra_image.total() * bgra_image.elemSize());



    RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Blit operation completed successfully");
}
catch (const Ogre::Exception& e) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Ogre exception during blit: %s", e.getFullDescription().c_str());
}
catch (const std::exception& e) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Standard exception during blit: %s", e.what());
}
catch (...) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Unknown exception during blit");
}

//    Unlock the pixel buffer
pixelBuffer->unlock();
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 07");

        // Set up material properties
        ogre_material->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->createTextureUnitState(material_name + "_texture");

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 07");

        ogre_material->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setSceneBlending(Ogre::SBT_TRANSPARENT_ALPHA);

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 08");

        ogre_material->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setDepthWriteEnabled(false);

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 09");

        // Apply the new material to the visual
        this->visual->SetMaterial(material_name);

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> OnTextureUpdate 10");
    }
    catch (const Ogre::Exception& e) {
        std::string ogre_error = e.getFullDescription().c_str();
        RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Ogre exception: %s, %s", ogre_error.c_str(), e.what());
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Standard exception: %s", e.what());
    } catch (...) {
        RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Unknown exception");
    }
}

    physics::ModelPtr model;
    rendering::VisualPtr visual;
    std::string initial_material_name;
    gazebo_ros::Node::SharedPtr ros_node;
    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::SharedPtr texture_sub;
    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr update_timer;
    int texture_count = 0;
};

GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(LandscapeTexturePlugin)
}

It crashes at
pixelBuffer->lock(Ogre::HardwareBuffer::HBL_DISCARD);
void* buffer = pixelBuffer->lock(Ogre::HardwareBuffer::HBL_DISCARD);

try {
    // Copy image data to the texture
    pixelBuffer->blitFromMemory(pixelBox);


//memcpy(buffer, bgra_image.data, bgra_image.total() * bgra_image.elemSize());



    RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Blit operation completed successfully");
}
catch (const Ogre::Exception& e) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Ogre exception during blit: %s", e.getFullDescription().c_str());
}
catch (const std::exception& e) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Standard exception during blit: %s", e.what());
}
catch (...) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Unknown exception during blit");
}

// Unlock the pixel buffer
pixelBuffer->unlock();

No exception messages. Please help.
P.S.
Now, if I make these changes:
// Comment this part...
// Lock the pixel buffer before writing
// void* buffer = pixelBuffer->lock(Ogre::HardwareBuffer::HBL_DISCARD);
// RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Buffer locked");
// try {
//     // Copy image data to the texture
//     pixelBuffer->blitFromMemory(pixelBox);
// //memcpy(buffer, bgra_image.data, bgra_image.total() * bgra_image.elemSize());
//     RCLCPP_INFO(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Blit operation completed successfully");
// }
// catch (const Ogre::Exception& e) {
//     RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Ogre exception during blit: %s", e.getFullDescription().c_str());
// }
// catch (const std::exception& e) {
//     RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Standard exception during blit: %s", e.what());
// }
// catch (...) {
//     RCLCPP_ERROR(this->ros_node->get_logger(), ">>>>>> Unknown exception during blit");
// }
// // Unlock the pixel buffer
// pixelBuffer->unlock();
// And add this part to replace commented...
    Ogre::Image ogreImage;
    ogreImage.loadDynamicImage(bgra_image.data, bgra_image.cols, bgra_image.rows, 1, Ogre::PF_X8R8G8B8);
    texture->loadImage(ogreImage);

    // // Set up material properties
    // ogre_material->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->createTextureUnitState(m_textureName);//material_name + "_texture");

    // ogre_material->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setSceneBlending(Ogre::SBT_TRANSPARENT_ALPHA);

    // ogre_material->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setDepthWriteEnabled(false);

    texUnit->setTexture(texture);

    // Apply the new material to the visual
    this->visual->SetMaterial(this->initial_material_name);

Then it doesn't crash, but doesn't update texture in Gazebo either

Any suggestions?

Well, it can be a bug in Gazebo, but I wonder if anyone tried to alter textures dynamically?
